# How to detect dragLeave

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, mouseout, angulardraganddroplists

In [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/) you have `dnd-dragover` directive at your disposal. I can't figure out how to detect a **dragLeave** event. The problem is that I can't use `ng-mouseleave` directive as it never gets called while an item is dragged. The same holds true for any other JS or CSS solutions.

Is there any way how to detect `dragLeave` event?

I have looked at this answer: [How to start mouseover event while dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614073/how-to-start-mouseover-event-while-dragging) However, all of the proposed solutions are working due to XY coordinates which I don't want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could solve this was to modify the library. The proposed change is [here](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/pull/253/commits/696f876a71c36b096b962b45ebcb2238a92e8739).