# Dragging disabling CSS hover

Tags: javascript, css

I have this mini test example: https://jsfiddle.net/3d6udf2n/.

When I start dragging the mouse from outside of the `Link` to the inside, it doesn't change the background and color untill I release the mouse.

My question is, how can I make it (with css or javascript) so the hover event works no matter if I'm dragging or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start mouseover event while dragging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614073/how-to-start-mouseover-event-while-dragging)

Comment: @Marcs - That's for dragging elements... I need a simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

Got it after some tests: https://jsfiddle.net/3d6udf2n/1/.

Still trying to make it so it's all the tags `a` and not just the elements with the id `text`.

Comment: I guess this will have to work for now: https://jsfiddle.net/3d6udf2n/3/.