# Changing CSS properties of an element while a file is being dragged

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, events

I have set up a drag and drop box on my Vue JS web app. The element is a simple div which handles a file when it is dragged and dropped onto it.

I used https://www.raymondcamden.com/2019/08/08/drag-and-drop-file-upload-in-vuejs as a guideline.

HTML:

```
<div v-if="status == 'upload'">
    <h3> Please fill the data sheet and upload it here!</h3>
    <div class="downbox" @drop.prevent="addFile" @dragover.prevent>
        <span style="font-size: 60px"><font-awesome-icon icon='cloud-upload-alt'/></span>
        <br>
        Click to Browse 
        <br>
        or Drag and Drop a File Here
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
addFile: function(e){
            let droppedFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;
            if ((droppedFiles[0].name).slice(-5) !== '.xlsx') {
                this.$swal({
                    text: "Please upload a file of type .xlsx",
                    title: "Incorrect File Type!",
                    icon: "error",
                })
                this.status = 'upload'
            }
            else {
            this.file = droppedFiles
            this.status = 'show'
            }

        },

removeFile: function(){
    this.file = null
    this.status = 'upload'
}
```

CSS:

```
    .downbox {
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-width: 6px;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: dashed;
  background-color: #7a2ab3;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.6s;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.downbox:hover{
  background-color: #c56bc5;
}
```

As you can see, the background colour is changed when you mouse over the div.

However when I am dragging a file onto the div, this change of colour does not show up. So I don't know whether it does not count as a ":hover" if you are click dragging a file.

Either way I would like to know what I can add to the code in order to make the CSS background-color property change when I drag a file onto the div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following solution (simplified here):

```
<template>
   <div ref="drag" :class="{over: isOver}">
      ...
   </div>
</template>


<script>
...
mounted () {
   // add the needed event listeners to the container
   this.$refs.drag.addEventListener("dragover", () => {
        this.isOver = true; // add class on drag over
      });
   this.$refs.drag.addEventListener("dragleave", () => {
        this.isOver= false; // remove class on drag leave
      }); 
}

</script>
<css>
.over {...}
</css>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can listen for `dragenter` and `dragleave` events to handle this. But it can be tricky if you have other elements within your drop target element, because those will trigger `dragleave` events on your drop target that you will want to ignore. But something like this should work:

```
<div :class="['downbox', drag_over ? 'over' : '']"
  @dragenter="dragEnter"
  @dragleave="dragLeave"
  @dragover.prevent
  @drop.prevent="addFile"
>
  <div ref="others">
    <span style="font-size: 60px"><font-awesome-icon icon='cloud-upload-alt'/></span>
    <br>
    Click to Browse 
    <br>
    or Drag and Drop a File Here
  </div>
</div>
```

In your event handlers, use `over_others` to decide whether to set `drag_over` to `false`, which you don't want to do if you are still dragging over a child element. (see also, info on Vue [$refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements))

You may have more difficulty with your 60px span and the font-awesome-icon, but you should be able to extend the same principle to those elements if they give you trouble.

```
data() {
  return {
    drag_over: false,   // dragging over the target OR any child element
    over_others: false, // dragging over a child element
  }
},
methods: {
  dragEnter(e) {
    if(e.target === this.$refs.others) this.over_others = true
    else this.drag_over = true
  },
  dragLeave(e) {
    if(e.target === this.$refs.others) this.over_others = false
    else if(!this.over_others) this.drag_over = false
  },
  // ...
}
```

And add the css class:

```
.downbox:hover,
.downbox.over {
  background-color: #c56bc5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution, apparently you have to use X and Y coordinates:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8615260/12448004